# XSLT for-each loop table output

Tags: xml, xslt, for-loop, scope

I want to create a table with XSLT where the process stages are headers and the processNo are the values.

```
  <PV_Batch masterBatchNo="KH8944">
    <tempTable processStage="Blending" processNo="KF0285" />
    <tempTable processStage="Coating" processNo="KF0282" />
    <tempTable processStage="Compression" processNo="KF0283" />
    <tempTable processStage="Granulation" processNo="12345" />
    <tempTable processStage="Granulation" processhNo="KF0284" />
    <tempTable processStage="Mixing" processNo="KF0286" />
    <tempTable processStage="mixing" processNo="K12035" />
  </PV_Batch>

Blending | Coating | Compression | Granulation | Mixing
KF0285   | KF0282  | KF0283      | 12345       | KF0286
         |         |             | Kf0284      | K12035
```

I am having problems with repeating values, whenever I have repeats, they just go out of bounds, like this.

```
Blending | Coating | Compression | Granulation | Mixing
KF0285   | KF0282  | KF0283      | 12345       | Kf0284  | KF0268  | K12035
```

Here is the code snippt within my table xslt stylesheet.

```
          <xsl:for-each select="//tempTable[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyComponent', @processStage)[1])]">

              <th width="" align="Left" class="tableHeaderRow">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@processStage" />
                </th>

          </xsl:for-each>

          <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="tempTable">
              <td align="Left" class="tableNormalRow">
                <xsl:value-of select="@processNo"/>
              </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second loop in the snippet that is shown has to do the same grouping that the loop for the header does:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tempTable[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyComponent', @processStage)[1])]">
      <!-- get current processStage -->
      <xsl:variable name="processStage" select="@processStage"/>
      <td align="Left" class="tableNormalRow">
      <!-- loop over all tempTable belonging to current processStage -->
      <xsl:for-each select="//tempTable[@processStage=$processStage]">
          <p>                  
              <xsl:value-of select="@processNo"/>
          </p>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If there are multiple values for a processStage this will put them each in a p in the same td, so this table:

```
Blending | Coating | Compression | Granulation | Mixing
KF0285   | KF0282  | KF0283      | 12345       | KF0286
         |         |             | Kf0284      | K12035
```

will consist of only 2 rows.

If however this should produce a table with 3 rows the solution is a bit more complicated.

---

**Edit:**

XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="processStages" select="distinct-values(//tempTable/@processStage)"/>

<xsl:variable name="maxRows"
    select="max(for $i in $processStages return count(//tempTable[@processStage=$i]))"/>

<xsl:template match="PV_Batch">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="tempTable" group-by="@processStage">
                <th width="" align="Left" class="tableHeaderRow">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@processStage"/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </tr>

        <xsl:variable name="tempTable" select="tempTable"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $maxRows">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="."/>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$processStage">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tempTable[@processStage=current()][$pos]/@processNo"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

XSLT 1.0 Solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="keyComponent" match="tempTable" use="@processStage"/>

<xsl:template match="PV_Batch">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each
                select="//tempTable[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyComponent', @processStage)[1])]">

                <th width="" align="Left" class="tableHeaderRow">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@processStage"/>
                </th>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>

        <xsl:call-template name="tr"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tr">
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each
            select="//tempTable[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyComponent', @processStage)[1])]">
            <xsl:value-of select="//tempTable[@processStage=current()/@processStage][$pos]/@processNo"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($temp)!=''">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each
                select="//tempTable[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyComponent', @processStage)[1])]">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//tempTable[@processStage=current()/@processStage][$pos]/@processNo"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="tr">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Tobias, indeed, I am trying to figure out a way to dynamically create the table since the data from SQL won't be the same, hence there certainly could be a table much greater than two rows.

Comment: @batman_in_disguise are you limited to xslt 1.0 or can you also use xslt 2.0?

Comment: I would prefer to stay with xslt 1.0.

Comment: I added a 2.0 solution... I'll see if I can come up with a 1.0 solution

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately the 1.0 solution does not work

Comment: it is working now, I was using for-each in the previous table. Thanks alot for the help Tobias.

Comment: but what if I have another PV_Batch set? That doesn't seem to work

Comment: should each PV_Batch generate its own table or should it be grouped together? Will they share the same processNo's?

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsF/1 <- here's a quick update with multiple batches, I modified the key to include the batchNo and adjusted the path's to the tempTable calls to not be absolut xpath expressions... hope that helps

Comment: they should generate their own tables and the processNos will be totally different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56225/discussion-between-tobias-klevenz-and-batman-in-disguise).