# XSLT 1.0 For Each if output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I know xslt 1.0 has been done to death however, i have spent considerable time researching an answer to my problem. I have seen the following questions:

[XSLT for-each loop table output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329420/xslt-for-each-loop-table-output)
[XSLT 1.0 Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903906/xslt-1-0-group-by)

I am trying to teach myself as best I can but time is getting away from me and I need to get this up and working.

Anyway I implemented what I thought was the solution and realized that some of my XML's have duplicate names in the for each and therefore the output is moving into the next column. I need Visio to be in the Visio column (or table header) and Project to be in the Project column etc.

Here is my XML Sample

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<v_Add_Remove_Programs>
        <ResourceID>12345678</ResourceID>
        <GroupID>5</GroupID>
        <ProdID0>Office14.PRJSTD</ProdID0>
        <DisplayName0>Microsoft Project Standard 2010</DisplayName0>
        <InstallDate0></InstallDate0>
        <Publisher0>Microsoft Corporation</Publisher0>
        <Version0>14.0.7015.1000</Version0>
    </v_Add_Remove_Programs>
    <v_Add_Remove_Programs>
        <ResourceID>12345678</ResourceID>
        <GroupID>152</GroupID>
        <ProdID0>{90140000-003A-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}</ProdID0>
        <DisplayName0>Microsoft Office Project Standard 2010</DisplayName0>
        <InstallDate0>20180219</InstallDate0>
        <Publisher0>Microsoft Corporation</Publisher0>
        <Version0>14.0.7015.1000</Version0>
    </v_Add_Remove_Programs>
    <v_Add_Remove_Programs>
        <ResourceID>12345678</ResourceID>
        <GroupID>330</GroupID>
        <ProdID0>Office15.VISSTD</ProdID0>
        <DisplayName0>Microsoft Visio Standard 2013</DisplayName0>
        <InstallDate0></InstallDate0>
        <Publisher0>Microsoft Corporation</Publisher0>
        <Version0>15.0.4569.1506</Version0>
    </v_Add_Remove_Programs>
    <v_Add_Remove_Programs>
        <ResourceID>12345678</ResourceID>
        <GroupID>331</GroupID>
        <ProdID0>{90150000-0053-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}</ProdID0>
        <DisplayName0>Microsoft Visio Standard 2013</DisplayName0>
        <InstallDate0>20171225</InstallDate0>
        <Publisher0>Microsoft Corporation</Publisher0>
        <Version0>15.0.4569.1506</Version0>
    </v_Add_Remove_Programs>
    <v_Add_Remove_Programs>
        <ResourceID>12345678</ResourceID>
        <GroupID>4</GroupID>
        <ProdID0>Office14.PRJSTD</ProdID0>
        <DisplayName0>Microsoft Project Standard 2010</DisplayName0>
        <InstallDate0></InstallDate0>
        <Publisher0>Microsoft Corporation</Publisher0>
        <Version0>14.0.7015.1000</Version0>
    </v_Add_Remove_Programs>
</Root>
```

Here is my XSLT

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>Add Remove Software</h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th>Visio</th>
                  <th>Project</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="//v_Add_Remove_Programs">
                  <xsl:variable name="DispName" select="DisplayName0" />
                  <xsl:if test="contains($DispName, 'Visio Standard') or 
            contains($DispName, 'Visio Professional')">
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$DispName"/>
                     </td>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="contains($DispName, 'Project Standard')">
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$DispName"/>
                     </td>
                  </xsl:if>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output I desire.

Resource ID | Visio                          |Project
12345678    | Microsoft Visio Standard 2013  |Microsoft Project Standard 2013

Thanks very much in advance really appreciate it.

Comment: Your XSLT does not match your XML. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry I have updated this.

Comment: I have posted an answer based on a guess regarding what the intended result is. If this is wrong, please add the expected output to your question (along with a short explanation of the logic that needs to applied in order to get it).

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. You've told us that you've tried to solve the problem; you've shown us some XML and some XSLT, but you've never said what you are trying to achieve or where you are hitting problems.

Comment: @MichaelKay my issue is stated here "XML's have duplicate names in the for each and therefore the output is moving into the next column. I need Visio to be in the Visio column (or table header) and Project to be in the Project column etc."

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for posting a response to actually help me and not criticize me. It shows your the processional one. I have amended the question as per your response. I cant paste images. Picture Resource ID, Visio, Project as column headings (A1, B1, C1) in excel. I just want A2 to equal Resource ID, B2 to contain Visio Standard 2013 and C2 to contain both Microsoft Project Standard 2010 and Microsoft Office Project Standard 2010 in the one cell. Hope this makes sense. thx again.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow this at all. You are producing a table. What does each row in this table represent? I assumed you wanted a row for each `v_Add_Remove_Programs` - apparently you want something else.

Comment: Also clarify if `ResourceID` will be the same for all `v_Add_Remove_Programs`, as it is your current example.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Hi Michael each row is the resource ID. Do you do consulting work? email me at Killrag@hotmail.com if you do. I guess im not explaining this well at all for some reason. If I show you will understand straight away. Dont want to waste your time any further. sorry mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to group by `ResourceID`. In this case, read up on [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). In this case you would define your key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="resources" match="v_Add_Remove_Programs" use="ResourceID" />
```

And to get the distinct `ResourceID` elements, which represent your rows, do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="v_Add_Remove_Programs[generate-id() = generate-id(key('resources', ResourceID)[1])]">
```

But you have an added complication, as it looks like you also need to get the distinct programs within each resource. So, you need to do a second lot of grouping with this key...

```
<xsl:key name="resourceNames" match="v_Add_Remove_Programs" use="concat(ResourceID, '|', DisplayName0)" />
```

And to get the distinct programs, for a certain type, do this..

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('resources', ResourceID)
    [generate-id() = generate-id(key('resourceNames', concat(ResourceID, '|', DisplayName0))[1])] 
    [starts-with(DisplayName0, $type)]">
```

Try this XSLT, which you can see in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKxa

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:key name="resources" match="v_Add_Remove_Programs" use="ResourceID" />
  <xsl:key name="resourceNames" match="v_Add_Remove_Programs" use="concat(ResourceID, '|', DisplayName0)" />

  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Resource ID</th>
        <th>Visio</th>
        <th>Project</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="v_Add_Remove_Programs[generate-id() = generate-id(key('resources', ResourceID)[1])]">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ResourceID" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="resourceList">
              <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'Microsoft Visio'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="resourceList">
              <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'Microsoft Project'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="resourceList">
    <xsl:param name="type" />
    <xsl:for-each select="key('resources', ResourceID)
        [generate-id() = generate-id(key('resourceNames', concat(ResourceID, '|', DisplayName0))[1])] 
        [starts-with(DisplayName0, $type)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="DisplayName0" />
      <br />
    </xsl:for-each>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Fantastic description thanks so much. I did read about  Muenchian Grouping but it looked kinda complex for a XSLT newbie. Really appreciate the in depth response Tim.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Add Remove Software</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Visio</th>
                    <th>Project</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="v_Add_Remove_Programs">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="DisplayName0[contains(., 'Visio Standard') or 
            contains(., 'Visio Professional')]"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="DisplayName0[contains(., 'Project Standard')]"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your example input, the (rendered) output will be:

[image]